# import errors in android

Tags: android, import, r.java-file

I imported a project. I see import errors in each file. In the problems view I have the following errors:

```
Project X is missing the required source folder 'Gen'
The project can't be built until the build path errors are resolved
Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
```

In my package Explorer view, I don't see the gen folder so that I could tweak it.
What should I do, i am new to android.

Comment: clean build your project. if still creates same problem, restart eclipse.

Comment: You should never "tweak" your gen folder... This is for the generated files only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether you have android-10 version installed.

Clean the application

Right click on project -> select Android tools -> Fix project properties

Re build the application.

Comment: when I clean the project, it shows errros occured during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the folder (if it exists) and do a Project Clean in Eclipse. Mostly this helps to recreate your gen folder.

You can try to recreate it manually and make it a source folder, too!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project build target and API level you're using match.